# How should I trigger alerts from the ViewModel?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, mvvm

I've asked this question of a few colleagues who I believe have good design sense. Interestingly, I've received varying responses.  So which option do you think best fits the MVVM pattern and why?

Say I have a requirement to show an alert icon when $ greater than $10k.

- Option 1: VM has property "Amount", XAML trigger and/or binding sets element visibility
- Option 2: VM has property "ShowAlert", XAML binds visibility using a bool to visibility converter
- Option 3: VM has property "AlertVisibility", XAML binds directly
- Option 4: Other (please explain)

Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: +1 for the n°2, but with a more business oriented label like `AmountHasReachedThreshold` than alert, which is more UI related

Comment: I like option 1 and option 2. But I think option 3 revealed too much of the implementation

Comment: @Will : this title rather better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case you have definite business rule `Shown WHEN > 10k`, it should be encapsulated in ViewModel rather than View because View is aware on HOW data will be shown rather then WHEN and WHY.

So I would suggest exposing both `Amount` and `ShowAlert` properties and avoid exposing `AlertVisibility` property because it scatter such WPF View specific things like [Visibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility.aspx) enum states (Hidden, Collapsed, ...)

If you would prefer to expose`AlertVisibility` you could face following problem in the future - just imagine that newer versions of WPF got rid of the annoying [Visibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility.aspx) enum and in this case you've to modify ViewModel to expose new Visibility infrastructure/property to keep View working fine, but this is not correct from the MVVM perspectives when a View behaviour encapsulated in ViewModel. So [Keep it Simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and expose straightforward `bool AlertVisible` property.

**EDIT:** Regarding naming suggestion in the comment

Absolutely agree! I would suggest renaming `AmountVisible` to `IsAmountSpecified` or something like this.

Comment: I would not call the property ShowAlert, I would call it something like AmountOverThreshold.  ShowAlert smells like View logic.

Comment: +1 for the good answer, but I agree with @cadrell0. Calling it `ShowAlert` sounds too much like you're putting view-specific logic in your ViewModel. I'd prefer to call it `IsValid` because the ViewModel doesn't care about how user sees an invalid value, it just knows the value is invalid. It's up to the View to figure out how to display the invalid values. (If the value can be invalid due to other reasons, such as text in a number field, and this is simply a special business rule, then I might use something like `IsThresholdExceeded`, or some other boolean name that makes sense)

Comment: I think it depends if this is a business rule such that you'll use it elsewhere OR if it's the view reaction to a value.  If it's just a reaction, then I would do as below.  But if you're going to need it else where, then it belongs in the VM as suggested by SLL and named like Cadrell0

Comment: Intention is very important.  For example, I have an application that shows a different icon to indicate whether or not a collection has items.  I think this belongs in a ValueConverter.

Comment: I agree with @cadrell0 that intention is important. If the variable alert is a true requirement (and part of the acceptance criteria) I strongly agree with the accepted answer and the test-ability argument. However, if it is merely a usability enhancement, then there is an argument for just exposing the Amount. The UI Logic of showing the alert, or whatever else is useful, could be controlled in XAML by a UX designer, without changing the VM.

Answer (score 0):

I would have my view's alert icon visibility bound Amount value through a converter which takes a parameter of the amount of 10000.  The converter would return visible or collapsed.

You could also have the VM send a message when it's over the threshold and any view or other viewmodels who care to listen for it can react to the message.

Comment: else, you'll have view logic in your VM